# Issue with multiple Session Factory/Transaction Manager/Transaction Template - Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We have a case where we need to define 2 session factories for the same datasource. In one of the session factory I have configured jdbc batching, the other one does not. Here's how the spring.xml looks like the below. I would like to keep the session factories different cause in some case we want hibernate batching, in others we dont.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
  ..datasource props here...       
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">${show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            ..packages here....
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>

<bean id="alwaysNewTransactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="sessionFactoryForBatching" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="show_sql">${show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${jdbc.batchSize}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_inserts">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            ..same packages here..
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManagerForBatching" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactoryForBatching"/>
    <qualifier value="txManagerBatch"/>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionTemplateForBatching" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManagerForBatching"/>
</bean>

<bean id="alwaysNewTransactionTemplateForBatching" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManagerForBatching"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW"/>
    <qualifier value="txnTemplateWithBatching"/>
</bean>
```

In the code I have marked a method as

```
@Transactional("txManagerBatch")
public void method(){

    // stuff happens here where we got to the database to get stuff

    txnTemplate..execute(new TransactionCallback<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            //stuff here that happens in the inner transaction
        }
    });

    //stuff happens here where we update the database    
}
```

In this configuration we get a session not found exception when the method executes.. Does anyone know why? We use spring 3.1.1 and hibernate 4.0.1

Comment: Are you using the correct transactionTemplate, transactionTemplateForBatching not transactionTemplate?

Comment: yup I am.. I checked and rechecked :)